# Is sed not able to match the first line of a file with the end of the address range?

Tags: linux, macos, sed

Sed is failing me on macos and linux:

```
$ printf "1\n2\n3" | sed -n -e '1,1p'    
1
$ printf "1\n2\n3" | sed -n -e '1,/1/p'   
1
2
3
```

The end address range pattern /1/ doesn't work. /2/ would though.

```
printf "1\n2\n3" | sed -n -e '1,/2/p'  
1
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (your) BSD `sed` examples, the line `1` starts the range, and `/1/` closes it, but the search for `/1/` starts only *after* line `1` (range start).

In GNU `sed`, there's an extension that handles your exact case, the [`0,/regexp/` range address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses). The docs explain it best:

> **`0,/regexp/`** A line number of `0` can be used in an address specification like `0,/regexp/` so that `sed` will **try to match regexp in the first input line too**. In other words, `0,/regexp/` is similar to `1,/regexp/`, except that if `addr2` matches the very first line of input the `0,/regexp/` form will consider it to end the range, whereas the `1,/regexp/` form will match the beginning of its range and hence make the range span up to the second occurrence of the regular expression.

For example:

```
$ printf "%d\n" {1..3} | sed -n -e '0,/1/p'
1
```